# How is it possible to add a .html file in templates directory and parse .html file in output in Pelican?

Tags: python, html, pelican

I am using Pelican to create a static site. What I want to achieve is to create a new .html file, let's say "contactus.html" in "templates" directory and parse it's output in "content" directory.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Do I get you right that what you want to achieve is actually a page, which does not foresee too many modifications? In this case, why won't you use the regular page functionality of Pelican? Putting another file in the templates directory is actually adding a template, which might be used to style a number of pages.

Comment: Thank you very much for that. My question is how to display the page added in the templates directory, in the output directory?

Comment: Terribly sorry to answer only now, I actually missed your comment.
What I found is a "template" field in "page" object, which allows you to choose the template to use while rendering the page (please check pelican docu [here](https://docs.getpelican.com/en/3.6.3/themes.html#page)) - hope it's the one you were looking for.

(edit 2 min later) I am not sure if adding a page in the template directory is right; basically, you have to add the template *and* the page in "content" and then that page can use the template through directive mentioned above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did @Alex N was to create a .md file in the content/pages directory and added attributes "save_us:contact.html" and "template:contactus". What it does in fact is to generate a contact.html file in content root page and get the info from the "contactus.html" placed in my template directory.

For any further questions please let me know.